# Как обратиться к свойству объекта, вложенного в объект?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Имеется код:

```
let user = {name: denis, photo: {small: 'url-1', large: 'url-2'}}
```

Как мне получить значение свойства small?

Пробовал так:

```
user.photo.small
```

Не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не работает, потому что там ошибка. Вы не обернули слово `denis` в кавычки, поэтому это не строка. Происходит попытка присваивания свойству `name` значения несуществующей переменной `denis`, в итоге получаем `Reference Error`.

Если объявить переменную `denis` (или просто присвоить свойству строку, а не значение переменной), то всё заработает.

```js
let denis = "denis";
let user = {name: denis, photo: {small: 'url-1', large: 'url-2'}};

console.log(user.photo.small);
```

Comment: Господи, как я этого не заметил то. Я час провозился, весь гугл перелистал. Спасибо.

Comment: @ДенисБеспалов Советую вам в первую очередь смотреть в консоль (Google Chrome / Opera: `Ctrl + Shift + J`), если что-то идёт не так. И ещё, проект даёт возможность отметить понравившийся ответ решением.